# Android HTTP POST using asynctask java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, android, concurrency, delay

//Global.java

```
package global;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Global{

    public static final String TLD          =   "local";
    public static final String SERVER       =   "http://m.server."+TLD+"/";
    public static final String POST_ADD     =   SERVER+"post";
    public static final String REQUEST_ADD  =   SERVER+"request";

    public static Context app_context       =   null;

    public static class post_to_server extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<NameValuePair>, String, String>{

        public String response_from_server = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<NameValuePair>... params){

            try{

                HttpParams param = new BasicHttpParams();
                param.setParameter("reference", "x");
                param.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
                param.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

                HttpPost http_post = new HttpPost(Global.POST_ADD);

                http_post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0], HTTP.UTF_8));
                http_post.setParams(param);

                HttpClient http_client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try{

                    HttpResponse http_response = http_client.execute(http_post);
                    HttpEntity http_entity = http_response.getEntity();
                    InputStreamReader input_stream = new InputStreamReader(http_entity.getContent());
                    BufferedReader buffer_reader = new BufferedReader(input_stream);

                    String buffer;

                    while ((buffer = buffer_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response_from_server+= buffer;
                        publishProgress();
                    }

                }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response_from_server;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        }
    }

    public static class is_connected extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            boolean response = false;

            try{
                URL url = new URL(Global.SERVER);
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    response = true;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
}
```

//Login.java

```
package com.website;

import global.Action;
import global.Global;
import global.Network;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.website.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends Activity{

    //Definitions
    //ll_   = linear layout
    //a_    = activity
    //link_ = clickable link
    //btn_  = button

    //Links
    TextView link_login, link_register, link_forgot_password, link_forgot_username;

    //Login Layout
    LinearLayout ll_login;
    EditText a_login_username, a_login_password;
    Switch switch_logged_in;
    Button btn_login;

    //Register Layout
    LinearLayout ll_register;
    EditText a_register_email, a_register_email_confirm, a_register_username, a_register_password, a_register_password_confirm;
    Button btn_register;

    //Forgot password Layout
    LinearLayout ll_forgot_password;
    EditText a_forgot_password_username;
    Button btn_reset_password;

    //Forgot username Layout
    LinearLayout ll_forgot_username;
    EditText a_forgot_username_email;
    Button btn_remind_username;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        Global.app_context = getApplicationContext();

        setup_interface();
    }

    private void setup_interface(){

        ll_login            = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_login);
        ll_register         = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_register);
        ll_forgot_password  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_forgot_password);
        ll_forgot_username  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_forgot_username);

        link_login          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_tv_login);
        link_register       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_tv_register);
        link_forgot_password= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_tv_forgot_password);
        link_forgot_username= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_tv_forgot_username);

        link_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setup_login_interface();
                hide_n_show_interface(ll_login);
            }

        });

        link_register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setup_register_interface();
                hide_n_show_interface(ll_register);
            }

        });

        link_forgot_password.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setup_forgot_password_interface();
                hide_n_show_interface(ll_forgot_password);
            }

        });

        link_forgot_username.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setup_forgot_username_interface();
                hide_n_show_interface(ll_forgot_username);
            }

        });

        //default layout screen
        setup_login_interface();
        hide_n_show_interface(ll_login);
    }

    private void setup_login_interface(){

        a_login_username    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_login_txt_uname);
        a_login_password    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_login_txt_password);
        switch_logged_in    = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.a_login_switch_keep_me_logged_in);
        btn_login           = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_login_btn_login);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(validate_login() && Network.is_connected_to_network(Global.app_context)){
                    new login_web().execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setup_register_interface(){

        a_register_email            =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_register_txt_email);
        a_register_email_confirm    =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_register_txt_email_confirm);
        a_register_username         =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_register_txt_username);
        a_register_password         =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_register_txt_password);
        a_register_password_confirm =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_register_txt_password_confirm);
        btn_register                =   (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_register_btn_register);

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(validate_registration()){
                    //post to server, requesting if username and email are available
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void setup_forgot_password_interface(){

        a_forgot_password_username  =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_forgot_password_txt_username);
        btn_reset_password          =   (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_forgot_password_btn_reset_password);

        btn_reset_password.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(validate_forgot_password()){
                    //post to server, requesting authentication to reset password
                }
            }           
        });
    }

    private void setup_forgot_username_interface(){

        a_forgot_username_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a_forgot_username_txt_email);
        btn_remind_username     = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_forgot_username_btn_remind_username);

        btn_remind_username.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(validate_forgot_username()){
                    //post to server, requesting authentication as sending a reminder
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private void hide_n_show_interface(LinearLayout layout){

        ll_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ll_register.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ll_forgot_password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ll_forgot_username.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private Boolean validate_login(){

        if(a_login_username.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_username),a_login_username,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_login_username.getText().toString().length()<6 || a_login_username.getText().toString().length()>15){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_invalid_username),a_login_username,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_login_password.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_password),a_login_password,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_login_password.getText().toString().length()<6 || a_login_password.getText().toString().length()>15){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_password_length),a_login_password,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private Boolean validate_registration(){

        if(a_register_email.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_email),a_register_email,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(a_register_email.getText().toString()).matches()){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email),a_register_email,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(!a_register_email.getText().toString().matches(a_register_email_confirm.getText().toString())){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_email_mismatch),a_register_email_confirm,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_register_username.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_username),a_register_username,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_register_username.getText().toString().length()<6 || a_register_username.getText().toString().length()>15){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_username_length),a_register_username,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_register_password.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_password),a_register_password,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_register_password.getText().toString().length()<6 || a_register_password.getText().toString().length()>15){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_password_length),a_register_password,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(!a_register_password.getText().toString().matches(a_register_password_confirm.getText().toString())){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_password_mismatch),a_register_password_confirm,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private Boolean validate_forgot_password(){

        if(a_forgot_password_username.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_username),a_forgot_password_username,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(a_forgot_password_username.getText().toString().length()<6 || a_forgot_password_username.getText().length()>15){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_invalid_username),a_forgot_password_username,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private Boolean validate_forgot_username(){

        if(a_forgot_username_email.getText().toString().matches("")){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_empty_email),a_forgot_username_email,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }

        if(!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(a_forgot_username_email.getText().toString()).matches()){
            show_error(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email),a_forgot_username_email,R.drawable.ic_error);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void show_error(String error_message, EditText txt_box, int icon){

        ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        SpannableStringBuilder error_string_builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(error_message);
        error_string_builder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, error_message.length(), 0);

        Drawable errorIcon = getResources().getDrawable(icon);
        errorIcon.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, errorIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), errorIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()));

        txt_box.setError(error_string_builder, errorIcon);
        txt_box.requestFocus();
    }

    public class login_web extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONObject ResponseObj = null;

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> post_params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            post_params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Action.action.toString(),    Action.login.toString()));
            post_params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Action.username.toString(),  a_login_username.getText().toString()));
            post_params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Action.password.toString(),  a_login_password.getText().toString()));

            Global.post_to_server post = new Global.post_to_server();
            post.execute(post_params);

            try {

                ResponseObj = new JSONObject(post.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return ResponseObj;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }
    }
}
```

//Network.java

```
package global;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class Network {

    public static final boolean is_connected_to_network(Context app_context){

        boolean response = false;

        ConnectivityManager conn_manager = (ConnectivityManager) app_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        //check for gprs connection
        //first check, whether the device supports SIM or not
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) Global.app_context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if(tm.getSimState()==TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
            if(conn_manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || conn_manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING){
                response = true;
            }
        }

        //check for WiFi connection
        if(conn_manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || conn_manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING){
            response = true;
        }

        return response;
    }

    public static Boolean is_connected_to_internet(){

        if(!is_connected_to_network(Global.app_context)){
            return false;
        }

        Global.is_connected conn_test = new Global.is_connected();
        conn_test.execute(Global.SERVER);

        try{
            return conn_test.get(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

//error.log

```
05-03 22:00:49.740: W/System.err(2094):     java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
05-03 22:00:49.756: W/System.err(2094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
05-03 22:00:49.757: W/System.err(2094):     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:503)
05-03 22:00:49.757: W/System.err(2094):     at com.website.Login$login_web.doInBackground(Login.java:349)
05-03 22:00:49.757: W/System.err(2094):     at com.website.Login$login_web.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
05-03 22:00:49.757: W/System.err(2094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-03 22:00:49.757: W/System.err(2094):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-03 22:00:49.758: W/System.err(2094):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-03 22:00:49.758: W/System.err(2094):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-03 22:00:49.758: W/System.err(2094):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-03 22:00:49.758: W/System.err(2094):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I do not understand what to am I doing wrong? my application crashes everytime on

```
Response = new JSONObject(post.get(30, TimeUnit.Seconds));
```

PHP output

```
{"string":{"1":"hello","2":"world"},"int":1}
```

I am able to get response from PHP with delayed response, if I comment out the Response code from android

Comment: Split that statement in two and check the return value of post.get() for null before you use it for a new JSONObject that not expects a text pointer which is null.

Comment: Well it's different... After post.execute you cannot use post.get() as an AsyncTask can be executed only once.. But post.get() is a bad idea as it runs on the UI thread.  You have very wrong code as you try to start another AsyncTask in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask.

Comment: `post = new Global.post_to_server()` Please rename that AsyncTask. Put something with (Async)Task in it as one would then immedialetly see that you indeed try to start another asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for AsyncTask to finish its job. use **onPostExecute** to call an outside method and inside that method get your JSONObject

```
Response = new JSONObject(post.get(30, TimeUnit.Seconds));
```